# Flutter StreamBuilder ListView not reloading when stream data changes

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I`m trying to build an app that loads an endless feed from a blog in a ListView. At the top, the user has a choice of filtering the feed according to a certain category through the "categorias" menu. When the user taps on the "categorias" menu, another ListView appears with all the available categories. When the user taps on the desired category, the app should return to the feed ListView display only the posts under that category.

**Expecter Result:**

- App call API and retrieves the 10 latest posts
- As user scrolls, the next 10 posts are retrieved through successive API calls
- User taps on the "categorias" menu and ListView with categories opens.
- User taps on the desired category and app returns to the feed Listview, makes an API 
  call to retrieve the first 10 posts of that category.
- As user scrolls, the next 10 posts of that category are retrieved through successive API
  calls.

**Observed Result:**

- App call API and retrieves the 10 latest posts
- As user scrolls, the next 10 posts are retrieved through successive API calls
- User taps on the "categorias" menu and ListView with categories opens.
- User taps on the desired category and app returns to the feed Listview, makes an API 
  call to retrieve the first 10 posts of that category.
- **Posts of the desired category are appended to the ListView and appear only after the posts
  that had been loaded previously.**

**My question:**

How do I have to modify my states or my Bloc, so that I can get the desired result?

**Relevant Screenshots**

[image: Articles Feed Listview]
[image: Articles Categories ListView]

**My structure:**

**PostBloc** - My bloc component, which contains the stream definition for Articles and ArticleCategory StreamBuilders. Also contains the methods for making the API calls to
get the articles and article categories.

```
  class PostBloc extends Bloc<PostEvent, PostState> {
  final http.Client httpClient;
  int _currentPage = 1;
  int _limit = 10;
  int _totalResults = 0;
  int _numberOfPages = 0;

  int _categoryId;

  bool hasReachedMax = false;

  var cachedData = new Map<int, Article>();

  PostBloc({@required this.httpClient}) {

    //Listen to when user taps a category in the ArticleCategory ListView
    _articleCategoryController.stream.listen((articleCategory) {
      if (articleCategory.id != null) {
        _categoryId = articleCategory.id;

        _articlesSubject.add(UnmodifiableListView(null));

        _currentPage = 1;

        _fetchPosts(_currentPage, _limit, _categoryId)
            .then((articles) {
          _articlesSubject.add(UnmodifiableListView(articles));
        });
        _currentPage++;
        dispatch(Fetch());
      }
    });

    _currentPage++;
  }

  List<Article> _articles = <Article>[];

  // Category Sink for listening to the tapped category
  final _articleCategoryController = StreamController<ArticleCategory>();
  Sink<ArticleCategory> get getArticleCategory =>
      _articleCategoryController.sink;

  //Article subject for populating articles ListView
  Stream<UnmodifiableListView<Article>> get articles => _articlesSubject.stream;
  final _articlesSubject = BehaviorSubject<UnmodifiableListView<Article>>();

  //Categories subjet for the article categories
  Stream<UnmodifiableListView<ArticleCategory>> get categories => _categoriesSubject.stream;
  final _categoriesSubject = BehaviorSubject<UnmodifiableListView<ArticleCategory>>();


  void dispose() {
    _articleCategoryController.close();
  }

  @override
  Stream<PostState> transform(
    Stream<PostEvent> events,
    Stream<PostState> Function(PostEvent event) next,
  ) {
    return super.transform(
      (events as Observable<PostEvent>).debounceTime(
        Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      ),
      next,
    );
  }

  @override
  get initialState => PostUninitialized();

  @override
  Stream<PostState> mapEventToState(PostEvent event) async* {

    //This event is triggered when user taps on categories menu
    if (event is ShowCategory) {
      _currentPage = 1;
      await _fetchCategories(_currentPage, _limit).then((categories) {
        _categoriesSubject.add(UnmodifiableListView(categories));
      });
      yield PostCategories();
    }

    // This event is triggered when user taps on a category
    if(event is FilterCategory){
      yield PostLoaded(hasReachedMax: false);
    }

    // This event is triggered when app loads and when user scrolls to the bottom of articles
    if (event is Fetch && !_hasReachedMax(currentState)) {
      try {
        //First time the articles feed opens
        if (currentState is PostUninitialized) {
          _currentPage = 1;
          await _fetchPosts(_currentPage, _limit).then((articles) {
            _articlesSubject.add(UnmodifiableListView(articles)); //Send to stream
          });
          this.hasReachedMax = false;
          yield PostLoaded(hasReachedMax: false);
          _currentPage++;
          return;
        }

        //User scrolls to bottom of ListView
        if (currentState is PostLoaded) {
          await _fetchPosts(_currentPage, _limit, _categoryId)
              .then((articles) {
            _articlesSubject.add(UnmodifiableListView(articles));//Append to stream
          });
          _currentPage++;

          // Check if last page has been reached or not
          if(_currentPage > _numberOfPages){
            this.hasReachedMax = true;
          }
          else{
            this.hasReachedMax = false;
          }
          yield (_currentPage > _numberOfPages)
              ? (currentState as PostLoaded).copyWith(hasReachedMax: true)
              : PostLoaded(
                  hasReachedMax: false,
                );
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print(e.toString());
        yield PostError();
      }
    }
  }

  bool _hasReachedMax(PostState state) =>
      state is PostLoaded && this.hasReachedMax;

  Article _getArticle(int index) {
    if (cachedData.containsKey(index)) {
      Article data = cachedData[index];
      return data;
    }
    throw Exception("Article could not be fetched");
  }

  /**
   * Fetch all articles
   */
  Future<List<Article>> _fetchPosts(int startIndex, int limit,
      [int categoryId]) async {
    String query =
        'https://www.batatolandia.de/api/batatolandia/articles?page=$startIndex&limit=$limit';
    if (categoryId != null) {
      query += '&category_id=$categoryId';
    }

    final response = await httpClient.get(query);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final data = json.decode(response.body);

      ArticlePagination res = ArticlePagination.fromJson(data);

      _totalResults = res.totalResults;
      _numberOfPages = res.numberOfPages;

      for (int i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++) {
        _articles.add(res.data[i]);
      }

      return _articles;
    } else {
      throw Exception('error fetching posts');
    }
  }

/**
 * Fetch article categories
 */
  Future<List<ArticleCategory>> _fetchCategories(int startIndex, int limit,
      [int categoryId]) async {
    String query =
        'https://www.batatolandia.de/api/batatolandia/articles/categories?page=$startIndex&limit=$limit';

    final response = await httpClient.get(query);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final data = json.decode(response.body);

      ArticleCategoryPagination res = ArticleCategoryPagination.fromJson(data);

      _totalResults = res.totalResults;
      _numberOfPages = res.numberOfPages;

      List<ArticleCategory> categories = <ArticleCategory>[];
      categories.add(ArticleCategory(id: 0 , title: 'Todos', color: '#000000'));

      for (int i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++) {
        categories.add(res.data[i]);
      }

      return categories;
    } else {
      throw Exception('error fetching categories');
    }
  }
}
```

**Articles** - contains a BlocProvider to read the current state set in PostBloc and displays
the corresponding view.

```
class Articles extends StatelessWidget{

  PostBloc _postBloc;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
        builder: (context) =>
        PostBloc(httpClient: http.Client())..dispatch(Fetch()),
        child:  BlocBuilder<PostBloc, PostState>(
            builder: (context, state){

              _postBloc = BlocProvider.of<PostBloc>(context);

              // Displays circular progress indicator while posts are being retrieved
              if (state is PostUninitialized) {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
              // Shows the feed Listview when API responds with the posts data
              if (state is PostLoaded) {
                return ArticlesList(postBloc:_postBloc );
              }
              // Shows the Article categories Listview when user clicks on menu
              if(state is PostCategories){
                return ArticlesCategoriesList(postBloc: _postBloc);
              }
              //Shows error if there are any problems while fetching posts
              if (state is PostError) {
                return Center(
                  child: Text('Failed to fetch posts'),
                );
              }
              return null;
            }
        )
    );
  }
}
```

**ArticlesList** - Contains a StreamBuilder, which reads the articles data from PostBloc and loads into the feed ListView.

```
class ArticlesList extends StatelessWidget {

  ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController();

  int currentPage = 1;
  int _limit = 10;
  int totalResults = 0;
  int numberOfPages = 0;

  final _scrollThreshold = 200.0;

  Completer<void> _refreshCompleter;

  PostBloc postBloc;
  ArticlesList({Key key, this.postBloc}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    _scrollController.addListener(_onScroll);
    _refreshCompleter = Completer<void>();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Posts"),
      ),
      body:  StreamBuilder<UnmodifiableListView<Article>>(
    stream: postBloc.articles,
        initialData: UnmodifiableListView<Article>([]),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if(snapshot.hasData && snapshot != null) {
            if(snapshot.data.length > 0){
              return Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                children: <Widget>[
                  ArticlesFilterBar(),
                  Expanded(
                    child: RefreshIndicator(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                            int index) {
                          return index >= snapshot.data.length
                              ? BottomLoader()
                              : ArticlesListItem(
                              article: snapshot.data.elementAt(
                                  index));
                        },
                        itemCount: postBloc.hasReachedMax
                            ? snapshot.data.length
                            : snapshot.data.length + 1,
                        controller: _scrollController,
                      ),
                      onRefresh: _refreshList,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              );
            }
            else if (snapshot.data.length==0){
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }

          }
          else{
            Text("Error!");
          }
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
        )
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
  }

  void _onScroll() {
    final maxScroll = _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
    final currentScroll = _scrollController.position.pixels;
    if (maxScroll - currentScroll <= _scrollThreshold) {
      postBloc.dispatch(Fetch());
    }
  }

  Future<void> _refreshList() async {
    postBloc.dispatch(Fetch());
    return null;
  }
}
```

**ArticlesCategoriesList** - a StreamBuilder, which reads the categories from PostBloc and loads into a ListView.

```
class ArticlesCategoriesList extends StatelessWidget {

  PostBloc postBloc;
  ArticlesCategoriesList({Key key, this.postBloc}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Categorias"),
        ),
        body:
        SafeArea(
            child: StreamBuilder<UnmodifiableListView<ArticleCategory>>(
          stream: postBloc.categories,
          initialData: UnmodifiableListView<ArticleCategory>([]),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return ListView.separated(
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return new Container(
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  child: ListTile(
                    dense: true,
                    leading: Icon(Icons.fiber_manual_record,color: HexColor(snapshot.data[index].color)),
                    trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
                    title: Text(snapshot.data[index].title),
                    onTap: () {
                      postBloc.getArticleCategory.add(snapshot.data[index]);
                    },
                  ));
            },
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(
                  color: Color(0xff666666),
                  height: 1,
                ),
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length);
      },
    )));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And here I am answering my own question...
In the end, I got everything to run smoothly by clearing the _articles List whenever a category tap event was detected.

So here is the new PostBloc

```
class PostBloc extends Bloc<PostEvent, PostState> {
  final http.Client httpClient;
  int _currentPage = 1;
  int _limit = 10;
  int _totalResults = 0;
  int _numberOfPages = 0;

  int _categoryId;

  bool hasReachedMax = false;

  var cachedData = new Map<int, Article>();

  List<Article> _articles = <Article>[];


  PostBloc({@required this.httpClient}) {

    //Listen to when user taps a category in the ArticleCategory ListView
    _articleCategoryController.stream.listen((articleCategory) {
      if (articleCategory.id != null) {
        _categoryId = articleCategory.id;

        _currentPage = 1;
        _articles.clear();

        _fetchPosts(_currentPage, _limit, _categoryId)
            .then((articles) {
          _articlesSubject.add(UnmodifiableListView(articles));
        });
        _currentPage++;
        dispatch(FilterCategory());
      }
    });

  }



  // Category Sink for listening to the tapped category
  final _articleCategoryController = StreamController<ArticleCategory>();
  Sink<ArticleCategory> get getArticleCategory =>
      _articleCategoryController.sink;

  //Article subject for populating articles ListView
  Stream<UnmodifiableListView<Article>> get articles => _articlesSubject.stream;
  final _articlesSubject = BehaviorSubject<UnmodifiableListView<Article>>();

  //Categories subjet for the article categories
  Stream<UnmodifiableListView<ArticleCategory>> get categories => _categoriesSubject.stream;
  final _categoriesSubject = BehaviorSubject<UnmodifiableListView<ArticleCategory>>();


  void dispose() {
    _articleCategoryController.close();
  }

  @override
  Stream<PostState> transform(
    Stream<PostEvent> events,
    Stream<PostState> Function(PostEvent event) next,
  ) {
    return super.transform(
      (events as Observable<PostEvent>).debounceTime(
        Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      ),
      next,
    );
  }

  @override
  get initialState => PostUninitialized();

  @override
  Stream<PostState> mapEventToState(PostEvent event) async* {

    //This event is triggered when user taps on categories menu
    if (event is ShowCategory) {
      _currentPage = 1;
      await _fetchCategories(_currentPage, _limit).then((categories) {
        _categoriesSubject.add(UnmodifiableListView(categories));
      });
      yield PostCategories();
    }

    // This event is triggered when user taps on a category
    if(event is FilterCategory){
      yield PostLoaded(hasReachedMax: false);
    }

    // This event is triggered when app loads and when user scrolls to the bottom of articles
    if (event is Fetch && !_hasReachedMax(currentState)) {
      try {
        //First time the articles feed opens
        if (currentState is PostUninitialized) {
          _currentPage = 1;
          await _fetchPosts(_currentPage, _limit).then((articles) {
            _articlesSubject.add(UnmodifiableListView(articles)); //Send to stream
          });
          this.hasReachedMax = false;
          yield PostLoaded(hasReachedMax: false);
          _currentPage++;
          return;
        }

        //User scrolls to bottom of ListView
        if (currentState is PostLoaded) {
          await _fetchPosts(_currentPage, _limit, _categoryId)
              .then((articles) {
            _articlesSubject.add(UnmodifiableListView(_articles));//Append to stream
          });
          _currentPage++;

          // Check if last page has been reached or not
          if(_currentPage > _numberOfPages){
            this.hasReachedMax = true;
          }
          else{
            this.hasReachedMax = false;
          }
          yield (_currentPage > _numberOfPages)
              ? (currentState as PostLoaded).copyWith(hasReachedMax: true)
              : PostLoaded(
                  hasReachedMax: false,
                );
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print(e.toString());
        yield PostError();
      }
    }
  }

  bool _hasReachedMax(PostState state) =>
      state is PostLoaded && this.hasReachedMax;

  Article _getArticle(int index) {
    if (cachedData.containsKey(index)) {
      Article data = cachedData[index];
      return data;
    }
    throw Exception("Article could not be fetched");
  }

  /**
   * Fetch all articles
   */
  Future<List<Article>> _fetchPosts(int startIndex, int limit,
      [int categoryId]) async {
    String query =
        'https://www.batatolandia.de/api/batatolandia/articles?page=$startIndex&limit=$limit';
    if (categoryId != null) {
      query += '&category_id=$categoryId';
    }

    final response = await httpClient.get(query);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final data = json.decode(response.body);

      ArticlePagination res = ArticlePagination.fromJson(data);

      _totalResults = res.totalResults;
      _numberOfPages = res.numberOfPages;

      List<Article> posts = <Article>[];

      for (int i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++) {
        _articles.add(res.data[i]);
        posts.add(res.data[i]);
      }

      return posts;
    } else {
      throw Exception('error fetching posts');
    }
  }

/**
 * Fetch article categories
 */
  Future<List<ArticleCategory>> _fetchCategories(int startIndex, int limit,
      [int categoryId]) async {
    String query =
        'https://www.batatolandia.de/api/batatolandia/articles/categories?page=$startIndex&limit=$limit';

    final response = await httpClient.get(query);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final data = json.decode(response.body);

      ArticleCategoryPagination res = ArticleCategoryPagination.fromJson(data);

      _totalResults = res.totalResults;
      _numberOfPages = res.numberOfPages;

      List<ArticleCategory> categories = <ArticleCategory>[];
      categories.add(ArticleCategory(id: 0 , title: 'Todos', color: '#000000'));

      for (int i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++) {
        categories.add(res.data[i]);
      }

      return categories;
    } else {
      throw Exception('error fetching categories');
    }
  }
}
```